# Trouble changing the font color depending on a certain date range in Javascript & CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, date

Here is the code I am attempting to change font color of the div if today's date is between the 25-28 of October, but doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know a better alternative?

HTML

```
<div id="masthead">
Some text here
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var today = new date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //Jan is 0!

if (dd<10) {
dd='0'+dd
}

if (mm<10) {
mm='0'+mm
}

if(mm=10 && dd>24 && dd<29) {
document.getElementById("masthead").classList.add('addToHeader');
}
```

CSS

```
.addToHeader {
color:red;
}
```

Comment: I found a mistake in first line and it is generating an console error 'var today = new date();' it should be like that 'var today = new Date();' 'Date' start should capital letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

```
var today = new Date(); // I modified here date() to Date
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //Jan is 0!

if (dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
}

if (mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
}

if(mm==10 && (dd>24 && dd<29) ){ // I modified mm=10 to mm==10 also added a first brackets
    document.getElementById("masthead").classList.add('addToHeader');
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys! Works perfectly now. Much appreciation for the fast response.

Comment: There will be multiple class or single class? if single then 'document.getElementsByClassName("masthead")[0].classList.add('a‌​ddToHeader');' would be better for support old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding bracket around the day numbers:

```
if(mm=10 && (dd>24 && dd<29) )
```

and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to extend this by changing the div ID to a div Class for "masthead"

Which method would I use and which works best with the following?

```
document.getElementsByClassName("masthead").classList.add('addToHeader');
```

OR

```
document.querySelectorAll("masthead").classList.add('addToHeader');
```

Comment: There will be multiple class or single class? if single then 'document.getElementsByClassName("masthead")[0].classList.add('a‌​ddToHeader');' would be better for support old browsers.